# Adjust start and end range for time list in Python

Tags: python

I have this magical incantation that I use (and understand) to populate a time field with the all hours of the day in fifteen minute intervals.

```
['%s:%s%s' % (h, m, ap) for ap in ('am', 'pm') for h in ([12] + range(1,12)) for m in ('00', '15','30','45')]
```

This prints out a list:

```
['12:00am', '12:15am', '12:30am', '12:45am', '1:00am',...
```

I am attempting to adjust that code so that it works for a start time and end time. For example I want it to start at 9am and end at 5pm. 
When the time comes back from the database it is a `time` object: `datetime.time(18, 0)`
What I tried to do was to take the `hour` of the `datetime.time` and start the range there. But my mind got kind of blown by the idea of adjusting it for am and pm.

**How do I adjust the code to work with a start and end time?**

Comment: It'd be best to use a 24 hour clock for the logic of the program and then make the conversion for display purposes.

Comment: This is for display purposes. I use this for the data: `['%02d:%s:00' % (h, m) for h in (range(0,24)) for m in ('00', '15','30','45')]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this. Write your own generator which works like `range` and takes a time-object (which comes from your DB if I understand you correctly) as start and stop (exclusively):

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
import datetime

def timerange(start, stop, step = datetime.timedelta(minutes = 15)):
    t = datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, start.hour, start.minute)
    stop = datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1 if start <= stop else 2, stop.hour, stop.minute)
    while t < stop:
        yield t.time()
        t += step
```

Now you can use it like this and it yields time-objects:

```
nineam = datetime.time(9, 0) #from DB
fivepm = datetime.time(17, 0) #from DB

for t in timerange(nineam, fivepm):
    print(t)
```

If you want it formatted, write another generator that returns a string according to your necessities:

```
def ftimerange(start, stop, step = datetime.timedelta(minutes = 15)):
    for t in timerange(start, stop, step):
        yield t.strftime('%I:%M%p')

for s in ftimerange(nineam, fivepm):
    print(s)
```

This also works if start is before midnight and stop after it.

---

Here a working sample:

```
>>> elevenpm = datetime.time(23, 0)
>>> oneam = datetime.time(1, 0)
>>> for s in ftimerange(elevenpm, oneam): print(s)
... 
11:00PM
11:15PM
11:30PM
11:45PM
12:00AM
12:15AM
12:30AM
12:45AM
```

Or with another step in the seconds-range:

```
>>> start = datetime.time(8, 5)
>>> stop = datetime.time(9, 12)
>>> step = datetime.timedelta(minutes = 3, seconds = 22)
>>> for s in ftimerange(start, stop, step): print(s)
... 
08:05AM
08:08AM
08:11AM
08:15AM
08:18AM
08:21AM
08:25AM
08:28AM
08:31AM
08:35AM
08:38AM
08:42AM
08:45AM
08:48AM
08:52AM
08:55AM
08:58AM
09:02AM
09:05AM
09:08AM
```

Comment: Shouldn't it stop at 1? Not at 12:45? BTW this is awesome.

Comment: @Johnston In order to keep it congruent and consistent with the builtin `range` I decided to take stop exclusively as `range` does. If you want it inclusive, change `t < stop` to `t <= stop`.

Comment: Excellent point. For my situation (which is opening and closing times) one should not be able to chose a closing time so it works perfectly.

Comment: @Johnston Glad to help. Generators are "la mera verga" as we would say around here.

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt `h` for a specific range:

```
['%s:%s%s' % (h, m, ap) for ap in ('am', 'pm') for h in ([9] + range(1,5)) for m in ('00', '15','30','45')]
```

However this won't produce 5.00pm as the range does not include the last time.